# How to do the convertion to Expression tree of lambda .Where() after .join() using anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

How to finish the convertion of the following query to Expression tree syntax, using an anonymous type in the .Where() and .Select()?

```
IQueryable<A> As = db.A
                     .Join(
                           db.B,
                           _a => _a.bID,
                           _b => _b.ID,
                           (a, b) => new { a, b })

                     //next two are the objective
                     .Where(s=> s.b.Name == "xpto")
                     .Select(s => s.a);
```

At this point I have (Thanks to @NetMage):

```
//QUERY DB with GENERIC TYPE
IQueryable<B> queryable = (IQueryable<B>)db.B;


// IQueryable<TOuter>
var arg0 = Expression.Constant(db.A.AsQueryable());

// IEnumerable<TInner>
var arg1 = Expression.Constant(queryable);

// TOuter 
var arg2p = Expression.Parameter(modelType2, "_a");
// TKey
var arg2body = Expression.PropertyOrField(arg2p, "_bID");
// also TKey 
var arg2 = Expression.Lambda(arg2body, arg2p);


// TInner
var arg3p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(B), "_b");
// TKey
var arg3body = Expression.PropertyOrField(arg3p, "ID");

var arg3 = Expression.Lambda(arg3body, arg3p);

// TResult 
var anonymousType = (new { a = db.A.FirstOrDefault(), b = db.B.FirstOrDefault() }).GetType();
// .ctor
var arg4Constructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors()[0];
// 
var arg4A = arg2p;
// pet.Name
var arg4B =arg3p;
// Type array
var arg4Args = new[] { arg4A, arg4B };

var arg4Members = anonymousType.GetProperties();

var arg4body = Expression.New(arg4Constructor, arg4Args, arg4Members);
// 
var arg4 = Expression.Lambda(arg4body, arg2p, arg3p);

MethodInfo joinGenericMI = typeof(Queryable)
.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
.Where(m => m.Name == "Join" && m.GetParameters().Length == 5)
.First();


var joinMI = joinGenericMI.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { arg2p.Type, arg3p.Type, arg2.ReturnType, anonymousType });
var qExpr = Expression.Call(joinMI, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

For the .Where() I tryed:

```
//.Where(s => s.b.Name == "xpto")
    //s
    ParameterExpression s = Expression.Parameter(anonymousType, "s");
    //s.b
    Expression left1 = Expression.Property(s, anonymousType.GetProperty("b"));
    //s.b.Name
    Expression left2 = Expression.Property(left1, "Name");
    //"xpto"
    Expression right = Expression.Constant("xpto", typeof(string));
    //s.b.Name="xpto"
    Expression e2 = Expression.Equal(left2, right);

    ParameterExpression t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "t");
    //BLOCK WHERE
    MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
         typeof(Queryable),
         "Where",
         new Type[] { typeof(A) },
         qExpr, // Queryable with join
         Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(e2, new ParameterExpression[] { t })); //'e2' is the where Expression, and 't' the input string for the comparison 
    //BLOCK WHERE
```

which raises something like:

```
InvalidOperation: No generic method "where" of type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the arguments, and the type arguments. You should not give type arguments if it isn't a generic method (this is a rough translation of the error).
```

And I bet that it will also be some trickery in the select...

How to do the convertion to Expression tree of lambda .Where() using anonymous type after the .join()?

Comment: The `join` returns an `IQueryable<'anon1>` and the `where` predicate is `Func<'anon1, bool>` rather than `Func<string, bool>`.

Comment: 'anon1 isn't recognized as a type. This: Func<'anon1, bool> , raises an error. I don't know how to use the anonymous type.

Comment: The type doesn't have a name, I was using `anon1` just as an arbitrary way to talk about it (like VS does in intellisense).  What I meant was that you need something _roughly like_ `.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where",
         new Type[] { anonymousType },
         qExpr, // Queryable with join, Expression.Lambda(e2, Expression.Parameter(anonymousType, "_b"))`

Comment: I kinda knew it, but was hoping it was something I didn't know :) (a kind of wierd obscure generic type that could be used in this context). Using the type 'anonymouseType' was one of my pre question try'es. I did exactly what you wrote, but unfortunately the result was: Error: "anonymousType is a variable, but is used like a type".  Thanks for your comment, really apreciated it.

Comment: Where did I use it as a type? I used `anon1` in my comment precisely to avoid that confusion. Sometimes I can't win.

Comment: Sorry, for my confusion. Its 3h40a.m... I'm around this for 3 or 4 days... I freaking dreamed with this... but can't get to the right answer. I'm learning linqPad, expression trees, but can't get it right... Again, Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, just for clarity, I think that your aproach is the right one . Unfortunatly I just don't know how to implement it :-(

Comment: If what you have shown has not changed, the following code produces a valid expression tree `Expression.Call(type: typeof(Queryable), "Where", new[] { anonymousType }, qExpr, Expression.Lambda(e2, s))` it does not crash. All variables in that code are as you have declared them in the question currently.

Comment: Why are you trying to build an expression tree manually instead of letting c# generate it from lambda? As I can see in you can change the definition of IQueryable<A> As variable to Expression<Func< IQueryable<A>> and use () => lambda, so the right side of the assignment will be parsed as expression. Also after that, you can add a breakpoint and view the correct expression tree generated by the compiler, thus you can find the mistake and fix your manual expression tree generation code with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this minified version of my `ExpressionExt` `class` for adding extensions to make `Expression` tree building somewhat easier:

```
public static class ValueTupleExt {
    private static T[] makeArray<T>(params T[] itemArray) => itemArray;
    public static T[] ToArray<T>(this (T, T) tuple) => makeArray(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);    
}

public static class ExpressionExt {
    private static Type TQueryable = typeof(Queryable);

    private static Type TypeGenArg(this Expression e, int n) => e.Type.GetGenericArguments()[n];

    public static MethodCallExpression Join(this Expression outer, Expression inner, LambdaExpression outerKeyFne, LambdaExpression innerKeyFne, LambdaExpression resultFne) =>
            Expression.Call(TQueryable, "Join", new[] { outer.TypeGenArg(0), inner.TypeGenArg(0), outerKeyFne.ReturnType, resultFne.ReturnType }, outer, inner, outerKeyFne, innerKeyFne, resultFne);

    public static MethodCallExpression Select(this Expression src, LambdaExpression resultFne) => Expression.Call(TQueryable, "Select", new[] { src.TypeGenArg(0), resultFne.ReturnType }, src, resultFne);

    public static MethodCallExpression Where(this Expression src, LambdaExpression predFne) => Expression.Call(TQueryable, "Where", new[] { src.TypeGenArg(0) }, src, predFne);

    public static ConstantExpression AsConst<T>(this T obj) => Expression.Constant(obj, typeof(T));

    public static MemberExpression Dot(this Expression obj, string propNames) =>
        (MemberExpression)propNames.Split('.').Aggregate(obj, (ans, propName) => Expression.PropertyOrField(ans, propName));

    public static LambdaExpression Lambda(this ParameterExpression p1, Expression body) => Expression.Lambda(body, p1);
    public static LambdaExpression Lambda(this (ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression) parms, Expression body) => Expression.Lambda(body, parms.ToArray());

    public static NewExpression New(this Type t, params Expression[] vals) => Expression.New(t.GetConstructors()[0], vals, t.GetProperties());

    public static BinaryExpression opEq(this Expression left, Expression right) => Expression.Equal(left, right);

    public static ParameterExpression Param(this Type t, string pName) => Expression.Parameter(t, pName);
}
```

You can take the query:

```
IQueryable<A> As = db.A
                     .Join(
                           db.B,
                           _a => _a.bID,
                           _b => _b.ID,
                           (_a, _b) => new { a = _a, b = _b })
                     .Where(s => s.b.Name == "xpto")
                     .Select(s => s.a);
```

And recreate it using an `Expression` tree with:

```
var aParm = typeof(A).Param("_a");
var aKeyFne = aParm.Lambda(aParm.Dot("bID"));

var bParm = typeof(B).Param("_b");
var bKeyFne = bParm.Lambda(bParm.Dot("ID"));
var anonType = (new { a = default(A), b = default(B) }).GetType();
var resultFne = (aParm, bParm).Lambda(anonType.New(aParm, bParm));
var join = db.A.AsConst().Join(db.B.AsConst(), aKeyFne, bKeyFne, resultFne);

var sParm = anonType.Param("s");
var predFne = sParm.Lambda(sParm.Dot("b.Name").opEq("xpto".AsConst()));

var where = join.Where(predFne);
var qexpr = where.Select(sParm.Lambda(sParm.Dot("a")));

IQueryable<A> AsE = new System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<A>(qexpr);
```

Comment: You my friend, are a life savier... you trully are a NetMage! Thanks

Comment: In the real scenario this method is used in a baseClass to search db to populate a table. In baseClass, 'A' is a Generic and B is just a string that I receive in a parameter (this means I have 'B', not B). I tryed to adapt your answer (wich is better than I've ever hoped), but i'm having trouble in anonType, param b (I dont have a type B, and with Activator.CreateInstance an Object (not B) is created) and in the join. Tryed db.Set(A).AsConst(), but that creates a DBSet and not a db.A has I hoped. Both raised exceptions. Is it possible to do? If it is, can I update question with it?

Comment: I didn't put those constraints on front because you are the only one who got to answer, and with more constraints it would be even harder to get any answer... like I said, your answer is beatiful and I learned a lot from it, and will refactor my code with it. I just need this (hopefuly) last adaptation. I can also open another question with those specific cases. Thanks for all the help! As i said... your are a life savior.

Comment: @DiogoAlmeida If you don't have type `B` at compile time, how do you intend to use the anonymous type that results? It is possible to create anonymous types at runtime but they are of limited use since they pretty much require reflection to do anything with (but ASP.Net using reflection a lot so...).

Comment: I have a string of B. ex. I have a string field = 'personId' that I split and get person , and can get Type of person which would do the join. But this Type is a variable, not a class that I can do a default(B) to create the anonymous used in the join. Performance is not a problem in this. Is it impossible in the present condition to do it?

Comment: @DiogoAlmeida No, but how you do it depends on how you intend to use the result.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your question. The result of the join, where, select is to be used to populate a table (I'm using list). The result of the B is going to be used to do the where, filtering by type B. Name. Don't know if this was what you asked.

Comment: Ooh, and to make it easier (just kidding), the query can have multiple joins like this one, in chain, with type C with c.Name = "some string", and C was created exactly has type B, and D, and E, and at the end get a list<A>. Each of those types, correspondes to a filter in a table.

Comment: the final object A, has objects for B, C and D. After this query, A will be mapped to ViewA, where there is a BName, CName, DName properties. Now, because of the joins, all data is available,  and no need for lazy loading for each of these mapped properties, for every row of table.

Comment: @DiogoAlmeida "used to populate a table (I'm using list)" - can you express that in C#?

Comment: My current method receives orderBy, skip, take and where parameters. For each 'where' it creates a binary comparition left (relation) right. Then the resulting expression is used in  a MethodCallExpression 'Where'. This is used with oderby. I get a IQueriable<A> with those, and finish it with: results.Select(a => a)
               .Skip(QueryParams.skip)
               .Take(QueryParams.take)
               .ToList<A>();
 I was thinking of chainning the join method to enter after the Where and before the orderBy (between methodCallExpressions) or before the call 'where'.

Comment: if it makes it easier, I can make a new question with existing code. Once again, thanks for you help.